# Using nest_by or nest, group_by or looping to perform several chi square test to several variables in R (likert scales)

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse, chi-squared

Let's say I have these categorical variables in my data set. All variables are related to the people's concerns of the COVID-19 and were assessed two times (with different participants..).

[image: dataset]

And my main goal is to check if `time` (will be "constant") is associated with the prevalence of each `item` (economy, social cohesion, and so on) (will vary). Therefore, I'll need to perform several Chi-square tests.

[image: chi-square]

I've followed some instructions using `nest_by` or [`xtabs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61912976/running-multiple-chi-squared-tests-for-different-categories) , but I'm not getting the right results.
I would like to keep the tidyverse environment in this analysis.

The main goal is to have several chi-squared tests, such as this one:

```
ds_plot_likert %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(time),
               names_to = "item", values_to = "response") %>% 
  group_by(item, time, response) %>% 
  summarise(N = n()) %>%
  mutate(pct = N / sum(N)) %>% 
  filter(item == "Children's academic achievement") %>% #need to change all the time...
  xtabs(formula =  pct ~ time  + response, data = .) %>% 
  chisq.test()
```

[image: chi-square]

But for all variables in my dataset (and preferably using tidyverse).

Thank you!

The following code gives you the possibility to reproduce.

```
ds <- structure(list(time = c("First", "First", "First", "First", "First", 
"First", "First", "First", "First", "First", "First", "First", 
".Second", "First", "First", "First", "First", ".Second", "First", 
"First", "First", "First", "First", "First", "First", "First", 
".Second", "First", "First", ".Second", "First", "First", "First", 
"First", "First", "First", "First", "First", "First", "First", 
".Second", "First", "First", "First", ".Second", ".Second", "First", 
"First", "First", ".Second", ".Second", "First", "First", "First", 
"First", ".Second", ".Second", "First", "First", "First", "First", 
"First", ".Second", "First", "First", "First", "First", ".Second", 
"First", "First", "First", "First", "First", "First", "First", 
".Second", "First", ".Second", "First", "First", "First", "First", 
"First", "First", "First", "First", "First", "First", "First", 
".Second", "First", "First", "First", "First", "First", "First", 
"First", ".Second", ".Second", "First"), Economy = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Not at all", "A little", "Moderately", 
"Very much"), class = "factor"), `My personal finance` = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Not at all", "A little", "Moderately", 
"Very much"), class = "factor"), `My own health` = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Not at all", "A little", "Moderately", 
"Very much"), class = "factor"), `My friends and family health` = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Not at all", "A little", "Moderately", 
"Very much"), class = "factor"), `Social cohesion` = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Not at all", "A little", "Moderately", 
"Very much"), class = "factor"), `Food and pharmaceutical drugs` = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Not at all", "A little", "Moderately", 
"Very much"), class = "factor"), `Price of grocery products` = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Not at all", "A little", "Moderately", 
"Very much"), class = "factor"), `Stock prices` = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Not at all", "A little", "Moderately", 
"Very much"), class = "factor"), `Children's academic achievement` = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, NA, 
4L, 3L, NA, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 
NA, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Not at all", "A little", "Moderately", 
"Very much"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```

Comment: What do you consider the "right" result, and what results are you currently getting?

Comment: Thank you! Five minutes and I'll edit the post

Comment: @G.Grothendieck done. Thank you! Jdobres, done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the result in a list for each `item` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ds %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(time),
               names_to = "item", values_to = "response") %>% 
  group_by(item, time, response) %>% 
  summarise(N = n()) %>%
  mutate(pct = N / sum(N)) %>% 
  group_by(item) %>% 
  summarise(test = list(xtabs(formula =  pct ~ time  + response, 
                       data = cur_data()) %>% chisq.test())) -> result

result$test

#[[1]]

#   Pearson's Chi-squared test

#data:  .
#X-squared = 0.0099329, df = 3, p-value = 0.9997


#[[2]]
#
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test

#data:  .
#X-squared = 0.026631, df = 3, p-value = 0.9989
#...
#...
```

Comment: Amazing.I didn't know the `cur_data` function. I was trying to use the `nest` function! Something like that `ds %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(time),
               names_to = "item", values_to = "response") %>% 
  group_by(item, time, response) %>% 
  summarise(N = n()) %>%
  mutate(pct = N / sum(N)) %>% 
  group_by(item) %>% 
  nest()`